# "@" symbol in .md file leads to broken links with MDRoam and OrgRoamUI?

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode

Recently, I am trying to use MDRoam and OrgRoamUI in emacs to manage .md files. A strange problem troubles me a lot. If there is "@" symbol in .md file, the graph render by OrgRoamUI will contains broken links. As Follows:

[image]

Md file content:

````html
---
title: Java Language
id: 2023-06-05T010809
category: 
---
# Test
there is a code block:
```java
  public class Main {
      /**
     @param args, parameter of main.
       ,*/
       @AnnotationTest("TestMain")
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("hello, world");
      }
  }
```
````

Is there anyone who knows some solution?